# qwraps2 group_by only partially applies on table

Tags: r, dplyr, qwraps2

I have tried out the qwraps2 package that seems quite promising.

However, when I have written a table like this:

```
set.seed(42)
library(magrittr)
library(qwraps2)
library(dplyr)


# define the markup language we are working in.
# options(qwraps2_markup = "latex") is also supported.
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")

data(mtcars)

mtcars2 <-
  dplyr::mutate(mtcars,
                cyl_factor = factor(cyl,
                                    levels = c(6, 4, 8),
                                    labels = paste(c(6, 4, 8), "cylinders")),
                cyl_character = paste(cyl, "cylinders"))

str(mtcars2)
with(mtcars2, table(cyl_factor, cyl_character))
with(mtcars2, all.equal(factor(cyl_character), cyl_factor))
mean_sd(mtcars2$mpg)
args(summary_table)

our_summary1 <-
  list("Miles Per Gallon" =
         list("min" = ~ min(.data$mpg),
              "max" = ~ max(.data$mpg),
              "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$mpg)),
       "Displacement" =
         list("min" = ~ min(.data$disp),
              "median" = ~ median(.data$disp),
              "max" = ~ max(.data$disp),
              "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$disp)),
       "Weight (1000 lbs)" =
         list("min" = ~ min(.data$wt),
              "max" = ~ max(.data$wt),
              "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$wt)),
       "Forward Gears" =
         list("Three" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(.data$gear == 3),
              "Four"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(.data$gear == 4),
              "Five"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(.data$gear == 5))
  )
whole <- summary_table(mtcars2 %>% dplyr::group_by(., cyl), our_summary1)
whole
```

On my server that doesn't allow me to output the example, a strange thing happen with the group_by that I can't figure out:

When I use the group_by function as above it does group_by in the column titles (thus as in the above example I get the number maching cyl = 4,6 and 8 (n = 11,7 and 14) as seperate columns. (the group_by are from dplyr)

However all statistics on the rows below are the same in each column and are a total of all (thus ungrouped). This is really strange and it doesn't throw an error, does anyone have any suggestion on how to proceed?

I am sorry but I can't provide a repoducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I did wrong.

```
list("Miles Per Gallon" =
         list("min" = ~ min(.data$mpg),
              "max" = ~ max(.data$mpg),
              "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$mpg))
```

instead of writing the `"min" = ~ min(.data$cyl == 4)` I wrote `"min" = ~ min(data$cyl == 4)` thus referring to the entire data every time. 
It works when I fix this:
`"min" = ~ min(cyl == 4)`

Comment: Starting with qwraps2 version 0.5.0 (released on 1 Sept 2020) the use of the `.data` data pronoun is no longer recommended.  `"min" = ~ min(cyl == 4)` should is now the norm.